# Sprint Wireless Toolkit 3.3.2 vs Sun Wireless Toolkit

Tags: java, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

Anyone know the diference between [Sprint Wireless Toolkit 3.3.2](http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/mobile_platforms/java_me/javame.jsp) and Sun Wireless Toolkit?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK both are same. But I feel some differents between Sprint toolkit and Sun toolkit. These are,

Sprint toolkit having Nokia, Samsung, LG emulators. But Sun java toolkit having their own toolkit.

Sprint support touch emulators. Sun toolkit doesn't have touch emulators.

Zooming emulator screen supports Sprint. Sun toolkit doesn't support.